# Interface 'XYZ' incorrectly extends interface 'DialogProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using a `Dialog` from `@mui/material` in one of my component. My component looks like this:

```
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentProps,
  DialogProps,
} from '@mui/material'

export interface AppModalProps extends DialogProps {
  header?: JSX.Element
  content?: JSX.Element
  actions?: JSX.Element
}

function AppModal(props: AppModalProps) {
  const {
    header,
    content,
    actions,
  } = props

  return (
    <Dialog
      keepMounted={false}
    >
        <DialogContent
          style={{
            padding: '20px 22px',
            overflow: 'visible',
          }}
        >
          {content}
        </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions classes={{ root: 'justify-start pb-0 pl-0 pr-0' }}>
        {actions}
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

But I get below error:

**Interface 'AppModalProps' incorrectly extends interface 'DialogProps'.**

**Types of property 'content' are incompatible.**

**Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.**

**Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

I tried to change the `AppModalProps` like this but then I get :

```
export interface AppModalProps extends DialogProps {
  header?: JSX.Element
  content?: React.ReactNode
  actions?: JSX.Element
}
```

**Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'**

package details:
"@mui/material": "^5.14.18",
"typescript": "^4.8.4",
node version : 18.18.2

`content` is being passed to `<DialogContent>` as `children` then why it is throwing error like :

**Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

Comment: It says that type of `content` should be `string | undefined`. what is your question?

Comment: @TalRofe I'm using `content` under `< DialogContent >` only as a children. then why it is expecting `string | undefined` ?

Comment: Do you use the latest version of react?

Comment: using react@18 version

Comment: content?: React.ReactNode should work.